# SQL function to lookup ID from Name

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Our reference tables each have a "Name" field with a unique index, plus an ID primary key. Is it possible to write a function like ID(@tableName varchar(100), @name varchar(100) that will return the ID? "EXEC" within functions does not seem to be allowed.  If necessary we could specify that tables that this would work with inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this approach (example for 2 simple tables)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (Id int, Name varchar(100));
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (1, 'Name1InTable1');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (2, 'Name2InTable1');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (3, 'Name3InTable1');


CREATE TABLE Table2 (Id int, Name varchar(100));
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (1, 'Name1InTable2');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (2, 'Name2InTable2');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (3, 'Name3InTable2');


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.f_GetIdFromTableByName 
(
    @tableName varchar(100), @name varchar(100)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Id int;

    IF @tableName = 'Table1'
        BEGIN
            SELECT @Id = Id
            FROM Table1
            WHERE Name = @name;
        END;

    IF @tableName = 'Table2'
        BEGIN
            SELECT @Id = Id
            FROM Table2
            WHERE Name = @name;
        END;

    RETURN @Id

END
GO
```

Run function

```
SELECT dbo.f_GetIdFromTableByName('Table2','Name2InTable2')
```